# Can this "attack" really cause quicksort to degrade to quadratic running time even if items had been randomly shuffled?

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort

[A Killer Adversary for Quicksort](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf) claims to have a method of reducing any quicksort implementation to quadratic time. I guess this means that it will always produce a list that will always take O(n^2) to run. This is saying something because, even though Quicksort has worst case O(n^2) it typically runs O(nlogn). The author claims that this still works even when the array is randomly shuffled before calling quicksort. How is this possible? I don't know C but here are the prerequisites and the code of the program

> The quicksort will be vulnerable provided only that it satisfies some
>   mild assumptions that are met by every implementation I have seen:
>   1. The implementation is single-threaded.
>   2. Pivot-choosing takes O (1) comparisons; all other comparisons are for partitioning.
>   3. The comparisons of the partitioning phase are contiguous and involve the pivot value.
>   4. The only data operations performed are comparison and copying.
>   5. Comparisons involve only input data values or copies thereof.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *val; /* item values */
int ncmp; /* number of comparisons */
int nsolid; /* number of solid items */
int candidate; /* pivot candidate */
int gas; /* gas value */

#define freeze(x) val[x] = nsolid++

int cmp(const void *px, const void *py) /* per C standard */
{
    const int x = *(const int*)px;
    const int y = *(const int*)py;
    ncmp++;
    if(val[x]==gas && val[y]==gas)
    {
        if(x == candidate)
            freeze(x);
        else
            freeze(y);
    }
    if(val[x] == gas)
        candidate = x;
    else if(val[y] == gas)
        candidate = y;
    return val[x] - val[y]; /* only the sign matters */
}

int antiqsort(int n, int *a)
{
    int i;
    int *ptr = malloc(n*sizeof(*ptr));
    val = a;
    gas = n - 1;
    nsolid = ncmp = candidate = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        ptr[i] = i;
        val[i] = gas;
    }
    qsort(ptr, n, sizeof(*ptr), cmp);
    free(ptr);
    return ncmp;
}
```

The general method works against any implementation of quicksort–**even a randomizing one**–that satisfies certain very mild and realistic assumptions.

By randomizing does he mean random pivot selection or randomizing the input structure?

Comment: I take issue with the claim "the only data operations performed are comparison and copying." Um. If you're using `qsort()` *you* don't copy *anything*; **it does**. And this comparator physically changes the underling reference array (`val[x] = nsolid++`) which is used as a partial basis for the comparator result (`return val[x] - val[y]`). In short, he cheats with a bogus comparator that modifies comparison data. He's "sorting" array indexes that are eval'd by dereference in a bed of data that is modified during comparator execution.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are mistaken, take a look at the original article: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/aqsort.c After you have prepared the data offline, access to the comparison function is not needed( you only need to know how it sorts which isn't hard to guess with integers ). Then you only need to send the array to the program and the sorter will perform in O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

The model the paper uses assumes that the attacker has control not only of the data, but the comparison function. Essentially, the comparison function lies about the data, pretending that the quicksort always happened to choose a really awful pivot. This is a very powerful capability for the adversary to have.

Comment: If he can counter the randomization (supposing it exists), with a similar technique actual worst-case input can trivially be constructed.

Comment: This is a slight exaggeration.  The assumption is that the attacker has access to the sort API, and that that API includes a comparison function. The trick is to use the comparison function to gain insight into the pivot selection algorithm.  At the end you have a data _sequence_ that will drive the algorithm to perform badly in any future API call. The example is C lib's quicksort. What they don't say is that you can trivially beat the adversary by selecting the pivot randomly and _not resetting the seed between sorts_.  Of course introsort trivially beats this, too.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The lie is that the data originally looked like that. The view of constructing worst-case input and the view of lying about the input are just two ways of looking at the same behavior.

Comment: @user2357112: Just thought you might want to add that, to show the situation might not be quite as dire as portrayed, but nearly so.

Comment: @Gene: That's not how I see the attack. You can use it that way for a deterministic algorithm (which includes fixed-seed pseudorandom algorithms), but it definitely looks to me like the attacker is supposed to be computing input on the fly, rather than precomputing input with a preliminary run and then feeding that input to the victim.

Comment: This is an invalid model of attack then. In general, comparison sorts inherently require a comparison function that defines a valid order relation -- things like transitivity and anti-symmetry -- and if this part of the interface contract is broken it's already game over. You can't use untrusted comparison functions.

Comment: @R..: Like I said, it's a very powerful capability for the adversary to have. They might as well dereference null or issue nasty `system` calls. We have to assume that the comparison function is carefully sandboxed and time-limited, but the overall sort is not.

Comment: @user2357112: I wasn't disagreeing with your answer, rather with the attack model of the paper. +1

Comment: You don't have to have any control over the comparison function, you only have to know( or guess ) how is the comparison function written, which in the case of integers isn't very hard. The array is constructed offline, and then fed to the sorter program.

Comment: @R.. Take another look at this link where you have a test case. You do not need to compromise the comparison function or the target system at all. All you need to know in general how the quicksort and the comparison f. work. Then you send the data to be sorted. http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/aqsort.c

Comment: @R.. I just reproduced it using VS12 lib qsort to create an array, and it produced O(n^2) on my custom quicksort.  qsort uses median of three my quicksort uses only middle pivot.

Comment: @reader: OK, I see. To construct the malicious input the program violates the contract for `qsort` (resulting in UB), but does so in a way that's likely to work (achieve the desired result) in practice.

Comment: @R.. There is no UB if you implement qsort manually for this purpose and call it qsort2.

Comment: @reader: Agreed. But a typical usage case would be running it against the target system's `qsort` for which you might not have source or resources to reverse-engineer. The intent is to be able to attack arbitrary implementations simply by calling them to develop the attack, and while this probably works well in practice, it's still formally UB doing it that way.